# How can I check face selection in edit mode

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, selection-tools

How can I check if the mesh in edit mode has polygons (Faces) selected or not via Python? I use Blender v2.79.

I am working on a face selection check for a tool. If no polygons are selected in the mesh, the output console should `print('No Faces Selected')`, if polygons are selected in mesh, `print('Faces are Selected')` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polygons can be accessed in Python from the object data. So we start at `bpy.context.object.data.polygons` to retrieve the polygons of the active object. Note that I assume the object is in Edit Mode. This yields a list of polygons, which then can be checked for selection by accessing the `select` attribute.

To check the first polygon in the mesh for selection state, use:

```
bpy.context.object.data.polygons[0].select
# this returns True if the first polygon is selected,
# or False in case it is not
```

To get the selection state for all mesh polygons, you can use list accumulation:

```
print([x.select for x in bpy.context.object.data.polygons])
# for the Default Cube, this should yield:
# [True, True, True, True, True, True]
# IF all faces are selected. Play with selection to see the change,
# but remember to tab in and out of Edit Mode to make Blender aware of the
# selection change before running the code again
```

Now, if you just want to know if there is at least one polygon selected, you can query if True is in that list:

```
print(True in [x.select for x in bpy.context.object.data.polygons])
# this prints True if at least one polygon is selected
```

An IF-statement now could be:

```
if True in [x.select for x in bpy.context.object.data.polygons]:
    print('Faces are Selected')
else:
    print('No Faces Selected')
```

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed description :3

Answer (score 5):

**Use an edit bmesh**

I would only use the `Mesh.polygons` collection for the simplest of tasks, otherwise for all else use bmesh.

- Does not require an edit mode toggle
- Is far simpler to work with IMO.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
# list of selected faces
selfaces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
if selfaces:
    print("%d faces selected" % len(selfaces))
else:
    print("No Faces Selected")
```

Changing selection in code

```
# invert selection
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select = not f.select

# to refresh and see changes
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2.79, look at the top bar to see the faces selected and for 2.8, look at the bottom bar

Comment: but show me the nummber of selection, but i need a function that checks if faces is selected in the mesh or not.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102648/15543)  Would need to "grep out" the values for selected faces from string.