# How to find polygon number of a structure in blender?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, faces

I have created a cuboid room in blender using python and it has 289 faces as shown in the stats (in the image). How can I find which polygon number a particular face is ?

For example, If I print the output of the number of polygons by

```
Code snippet: 
mesh = ob.data
face_list = [face for face in mesh.polygons]
print('Face list: ', face_list)

Output: 
bpy.data.meshes['new_mesh.001'].polygons[0], 
bpy.data.meshes['new_mesh.001'].polygons[1] ... bpy.data.meshes['new_mesh.001'].polygons[288]
```

I want to know which face belong to which polygon number. Is there a way to find this ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use indices (small blue number) you have to enable the Interface > Display > [X] Developer Extras in the User Preferences dialog to see this option.
[image]

Or use MeasureIt Tools (build-in)
[image]

Comment: You should mention in your answer that you have to enable the *Interface > Display > [X] Developer Extras* in the *User Preferences* dialog to see this option.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

For Python: The index is stored in `face.index`.

Related question: [How can I check face selection in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128549/how-can-i-check-face-selection-in-edit-mode)

To print the indexes of all selected faces in *Edit* mode:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
# check the selected faces
for f in bm.faces:
    if f.select:
        print(f.index)
```