# Addon or featurs in Blender capable of profiling scene?

Tags: add-on

Im looking for a addon or a feature in blender that can analyse my models. I get them from an engineering department and some of the contain for an example small springs (highly detailed shape), which count up 30k triangles. Therefore the entire thing could easily end up being 250k triagles.

I need something that can profil my scene and tell me maybe a list with each mesh and their respective vert, tris, face counts

Any ideas from the comunity.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102597/finding-vertices-edges-faces-and-tris-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, with which you can retrieve information about the imported objects in your .blend file.

**The Outliner** shows all object in a hierarchy in the scene. In Object Mode, the *header* will show the vertex, face and triangle count of all objects. You can select objects in the outliner and the 3D View.

[image: outliner information]

Expand an objects hierarchy with the **+** icon. It will reveal a mesh datablock. Click on the mesh datablock to enter *Edit Mode*. In Edit Mode, you can manipulate the vertices, edges and faces in the 3D View. The header will now show the Verts, Faces, Tris count of only this selected object.

[image: single objects info]

#### Scripted

You can load a simple script into Blender's Text Editor and execute it from there. The following script will write the name, vertex count, edge count and face count to a file which is specified in line 4. You will have to change the path according to your needs.

[image: run script]

```
import bpy
import os

path = "U:/PWP/Desktop/info.csv"

with open(path, 'w+') as f:
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        v = len(ob.data.vertices)
        e = len(ob.data.edges)
        p = len(ob.data.polygons)
        tris = sum(len(p.vertices) - 2 for p in ob.data.polygons)

        f.write(ob.name)

        for data in [v, e, p, tris]:
            f.write(',' + str(data))
        f.write('\n')
```

<sup>*Tris count added from batfinger's comment to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102600/30849). Excluded in the table below.*</sup>

The created csv file can be opened in various applications such as Notepad or any Office Suite.

[image: csv file]

Comment: For tri count https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102597/finding-vertices-edges-faces-and-tris-using-python

Comment: @bat Added it, ty. Very smart.