# How to form a tapered stamp from an SVG

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude, svg

I am trying to make a stamp from an SVG. I have found a model on thingiverse that demonstrates the desired outcome well.

Given an SVG, and a "body" mesh:

[image: parts]

I would like to make a stamp where the body tapers into the impression:

[image]

I am very new to blender, and have been trying all manner of boolean operations and extruding, but am stumped on how to create something as elegant as this - preferably without lots of vertex nudging.

I believe the example was done in fusion 360.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This result can be achieved easily using basic operations.

1. Connect parts of your shape, so it only has one edge (select 4 vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd> and repeat)
2. Connect it to a circle (or your handle)
3. Add some ridges and move your shape upwards to taper it.

*Make one outside edge and connect it to a circle (or other shape)*

[image]

*Extrude it to make a handle (unless you already have one)*

[image]

*Add some ridges and move the shape upwards, it will taper nicely.*

[image]

Comment: C'mon you're making that look easier than it really is...

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Seeing your technique has literally quadrupled my competence.

Comment: Happy to help :). If you get stuck anywhere, feel free to ask. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Taking the inspiration from Jachyms answer I managed to produce the following stamp:

[image: stamp]

My technique was slightly different, as the geometry of the SVG is pretty complicated and I kept losing track of which faces I wanted to keep (is there a way to mark faces in some way?), but I would not have known how to approach this if it weren't for Jachym.

For those interested, my approach was:

- extrude SVG
- "Fatten" one side to get the taper
- Reduce the number of vertexes on the fattened side, by selecting and merging by distance
- Manually nudge some of the vertices so I have a defined permimter
- Create a circle
- Manually bridge the vertices (I suppose I could have used edge loop, but I kept losing count of the vertices - ADHD fun). Maybe theres an easier way to display selected vertice count?
- Extrude out the handle.

No doubt the geometry is appalling (its evident that there is lots of internal criss-crossing of edges - maybe there is a way to easily clean this up?), but it seems to slice ok for 3d printing, which means its ok for my purposes (pottery stamp), but I appreciate that Jachyms answer is the correct approach for this kind of thing.

Comment: Every solution that works for you is a good one :).
Btw, the (selected) vertex count is in [the bottom status bar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166273/78972) when in Edit mode.

Comment: Thanks - I cant believe I couldnt see it staring at me :D

Comment: You can make vertex groups of vertices implicitly selected when you select faces, or you can mark faces by giving them an arbitrary material ... you can select by material just under the material slots. That does mean you have to have two materials assigned, but they can look identical.

Comment: Thanks Robin - that will help a lot.